# Re-structure n-level array with parent/child relation (PHP)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I want to restructure an array and some of the solutions on stuckoverflow helped me to make it "proper" for the 1-st level items, but you'll notice the array is n-level deep.

The method **restructure()** is not used recursively (it should be). It's probably wrong alltogether, and have no idea how to make it right.

The *children* key says there are children with the respective id's, *parent* key links the item to the parent id.

```
class FilterMenu {

    protected $tree = array();

    static protected $structure = array();

    public function __construct(array $tree)
    {
        $this->tree = $tree;
    }

    public function getStructure()
    {
        self::restructure($this->tree);
        return self::$structure;
    }

    static public function restructure(array $structure)
    {
        foreach ($structure as $k => $v)
        {
            if (isset($v['parent']) and isset($v['children']) and count($v['children']) == 1)
            {
                // only 1 child
                self::$structure[$k] = current(array_keys($v['children']));
            }
            elseif (isset($v['children']))
            {
                $keys = array_keys($v['children']);
                self::$structure[$k] = array_combine($keys, $keys); // mirror array

                //self::restructure($v['children']);
            }
            else
            {
                // no children
                self::$structure[$k] = $k;
            }
        }
    }
}



// test array

$tree = array(
    1 => array(
        'parent' => 1
    ),
    2 => array(
        'parent' => 2,
        'children' => array(
            3 => array(
                'parent' => 2
            ),
            6 => array(
                'parent' => 2,
                'children' => array(
                    10 => array(
                        'parent' => 6,
                        'children' => array(
                            4 => array(
                                'parent' => 10
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    7 => array(
        'parent' => 7,
        'children' => array(
            11 => array(
                'parent' => 7
            )
        )
    ),
    14 => array(
        'parent' => 14,
        'children' => array(
            15 => array(
                'parent' => 14,
            ),
            16 => array(
                'parent' => 14,
            ),
            19 => array(
                'parent' => 14,
            ),
            20 => array(
                'parent' => 14,
            ),
            21 => array(
                'parent' => 14,
            ),
        )
    )
);

// test:
$tree = new FilterMenu($tree);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($tree->getStructure(), true);
```

Actual result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => Array
        (
            [3] => 3
            [6] => 6
        )

    [7] => 11
    [14] => Array
        (
            [15] => 15
            [16] => 16
            [19] => 19
            [20] => 20
            [21] => 21
        )

)
```

the desired/expected result is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => Array
        (
            [3] => 3
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [10] => 4 // <-- array with n-levels...
                )

        )

    [7] => 11
    [14] => Array
        (
            [15] => 15
            [16] => 16
            [19] => 19
            [20] => 20
            [21] => 21
        )

)
```

Here is the [link to codepad](http://codepad.org/Gag5Ullb#output) that tests the class and the array.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
function collapse(&$array) {
  foreach ($array as $k => &$v) {
    if (array_key_exists('children', $v)) {
      collapse($v['children']);
      $array[$k] = $v['children'];
    } else {
      $array[$k] = $k;
    }
  }
}
```

which, when called like this:

```
collapse($tree);
print_r($tree);
```

produces:

```
Array (
  [1]  => 1
  [2]  => Array (
            [3] => 3
            [6] => Array (
                     [10] => Array (
                               [4] => 4
                             )
                   )
          )
  [7]  => Array (
            [11] => 11
          )
  [14] => Array (
            [15] => 15
            [16] => 16
            [19] => 19
            [20] => 20
            [21] => 21
         )
)
```

See http://codepad.org/8atfSWGC

Comment: Kudos to you @Tomalak! Your solution does exactly what I need in the final output, even tho the structure is slightly different form what I expected. This example class is a stripped version, but "collapse" solution fits perfectly... have to figure it out how and why :)

Comment: @verb8 The above does the right thing, your expected structure is wrong. Note that this solution modifies the original array. If you don't want that, you must adapt the function.

Comment: Here's the hanging function as class method http://codepad.org/O3JV5rQe Cheers mate :)

Comment: @verb8 Nice. A lot simpler than your orignial approach, too. :)